# Getting time values from an Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, vba, office-interop

```
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = 
                                new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

      Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fname);
      Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];

      // read some data                    
      var Monday = ws.get_Range("D11");
      var Tuesday = ws.get_Range("D13");
```

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`to retrieve hours worked from an Excel sheet. My code seems to be working properly however I keep getting the values `COM Object` for `Monday` and `Tuesday`.

Why is it not returning the actual values in cell D11 and D13 from my spreadsheet??

I am also getting the same `COM Object` values for `ws` and `wb`, not sure if this has any relevance thought I would just throw that out there.

Comment: Is there perhaps a function in `D11`?  Try adding `.value` to your `get_range`

Comment: @paqogomez: Yes there is. I did what you said and it worked, except it returned a value of 0.4 something and the value in the cell is 11 hours so im not sure how its getting the 0.4 now

Comment: Time is held as a (Seconds since midnight)/(Seconds in day).  Therefore 11 hours is 11/24 which is .458.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: Thanks that makes more sense now, could you give an example of how to convert that into a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: As an aside, the date is held as days since 31 December 1899.  So if a cell holds a date and time, the integer part defines the date and the fraction defines the time.  Here in the UK it is 14 May 2014 00:18 which is held as 41773.0129.

Comment: With VBA `Format(41773.0129, "d mmm yy h:mm:ss")` returns `14 May 14 0:18:35`.  Use the c# equivalent of `Format`.

Comment: or if you just want the string representation use `ws.get_Range("D11").Text;`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to get it to work by using `Monday = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(ws.get_Range("D11").Value))`

Answer (score 2):

MS Excel stores the dates as float values. The integer part represents the days and the fractional part keeps the hours, minutes and seconds.

Check this code that extracts the hours and also the minutes and seconds, maybe you need them:

```
float excelValue = 0.4f;

int miliseconds = (int)Math.Round(excelValue*86400000);
int hour = miliseconds/( 60/*minutes*/*60/*seconds*/*1000 );
miliseconds = miliseconds - hour*60/*minutes*/*60/*seconds*/*1000;
int minutes = miliseconds/( 60/*seconds*/*1000 );
miliseconds = miliseconds - minutes*60/*seconds*/*1000;
int seconds = miliseconds/1000;
```