# Java - Get timestamp from excel file without converting to decimal

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have a cell in excel which has a timestamp value "12:30:00", when I get the value of the cell from excel to a variable in Java it is getting converted to decimal value (0.520833333333333). How do I retain the same time stamp value or convert the decimal to timestamp value accordingly.

Comment: What Framework/API do you use to read the Excel file?

Comment: I am using Apache POI to read from excel file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading time values from spreadsheet using poi api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710888/reading-time-values-from-spreadsheet-using-poi-api)

Answer (score 2):

Dates and I assume time values as well are stored numerically in Excel. They need to be processed specifically when using *Apache POI*.

You could try the following in order to deal with this.

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
  // Dates count as numeric and must be handled separately
  if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    timeFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
  }
}
```

This is of course just an example and it worked in a simple test case. I entered **12:30:00** into a cell and it was recognized as a date and I fetched the `Date` object and extracted the time from it.
The `DateUtil` which I used to check is part of *Apache POI*. It also has a few other functions which might be helpful to you.

You should be aware however, that this works for a very specific case. Namely the time being stored as a date.
It could be stored as simple text as well if the cell format was changed in the source file.

In my experience it's not enough to only handle the expected case. You usually need to deal with the different cell types *(at least Numeric and String, maybe Formula as well)* in a switch statement just to be save.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal value you are retrieving `0.520833333333333` is actually `12.5/24` so it is a fraction of a day.

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel stores the dates as float values. The integer part represents the days and the fractional part keeps the hours, minutes and seconds.

Check this answer:
[Getting time values from an Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642985/getting-time-values-from-an-excel-sheet)